# Quiero esperar a la respuesta del Request,bloqueando la pantalla de usuario con un Progressbar Android - JAVA

Tags: java, android

Buenas soy primerizo en Android (Java) y quiero obtener la respuesta del request bloqueando la pantalla de usuario con un Progressbar mientras termina.

```
Intent intent= new Intent(iniciarSesion.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("id",id);
intent.putExtra("nom_usu",nom_usu);
intent.putExtra("equipo",equipo);
intent.putExtra("password",password);
startActivity(intent);

if (equipo.equals("S")) {
    añadirequipo x =  new añadirequipo();
    x.nombreCancha(id,getApplicationContext());
}

public void nombreCancha(String idUsuario,Context mContext) {
    String URL="url"+idUsuario+"";
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    id_equipo = jsonObject.getString("idequipo");
                    id_usu = jsonObject.getString("idusuario");
                    nombre_equipo = jsonObject.getString("nombre_equipo");
                    cancha = jsonObject.getString("cancha");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.v("Fallo_Json:", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if (error.toString().equals("com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value null of type org.json.JSONObject$1 cannot be converted to JSONArray")){
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "No existe ese usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Fallo json"+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.v ("Fallo_Listener:", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

El metodo nombreCancha fija una variable String cancha que luego se recupera en un fragment

```
public String esperarNombre() {
    return cancha;
}
```

Lo que pasa es que se carga antes el fragment de que termine el response , quiero que la aplicacion se pare mientras se termina el response y colocar un Progressbar mientras termina.

Se que el Request un hilo async y **no quiero** hacerlo sync quiero que la aplicación espere a que termine eso con una barra de carga.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si queres que el request cargue mientras la pantalla muestra un loading deberias hacerlo algo asi:

```
void iniciarCargaDeDatos(){
  mostrarLoading();
  ejecutarRequest();
}

void mostrarLoading(){
  contenido.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  errorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

void mostrarContenido(){
  contenido.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  errorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

void mostrarError()(){
  contenido.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  errorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

void ejecutarRequest(){
  JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest=new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
        //Despues de terminar de recuperar los datos cargamos los datos en la pantalla y la mostramos
        mostrarContenido();
      }, 
  new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
      //Despues de parsear el error te recomiendo mostrar una pantalla de error
      mostrarError();
    }
  });

  requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
  requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

Quite todo el codigo del tratamiento de datos que le haces en el request para que sea mas clara la idea, vos despues agregalo para que te funcione todo.

Comment: Una pregunta,el view debe ser en el login o en la view despues del login,la llamada al request se produce al pulsar en el boton de iniciar sesio, Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Esta forma usala para cuando estes cargando datos de una misma pantalla, por ejemplo recargando una lista, buscando el detalle de algun item de una lista, etc. Para login yo cambiariiia "mostrarContenido" por "irALaHome" y pondria ahí el startActivity() que te lleve a la siguiente pantalla. Entonces quedaria el loading en la misma pantalla de Login y si todo salio bien te entra a la home, sino mostrar un error y listo.

Comment: Si puedes echarle un vistazo a esta pregunta te lo agradeceria https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/322418/scrollview-no-me-funciona