# ScrollView no me funciona

Tags: java, android

Hola buenas tengo un probleman,no me funciona el ScrollView lo he probado todo y no hay manera de que se active,estoy tratando de meter una lista dinamica en textview dentro de la scrollview

El xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

tools:context=".Resultados">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameResultados"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Mi java:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_resultados,container,false);
 for (resultadosBean temp : lista) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        textView.setText(temp.getFecha());
        contenedor.addView(textView);

        TextView textView2 = new TextView(mContext);
        textView2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderesultados);
        textView2.setText(temp.getHome()+" "+temp.getR_home());
        textView2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView2.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
        contenedor.addView(textView2);

        TextView textView3 = new TextView(mContext);
        textView3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.borderesultados);
        textView3.setText(temp.getAway()+" "+temp.getR_away());
        textView3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView3.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
        contenedor.addView(textView3);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView2.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView3.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
```

Y en el AndroidManifest tengo esto porque tengo una barra superior,no se si afectara al scrollview:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Algo de esto puede afectar a que no aparezca los scrolls?
He probado a cambiar el estilo del ScrollView ambos a match_parent,a como esta ahora ,he probado un RelativeLayour en vez de un LinearLayout,el fillViewport true,false sin poner.

[image: Asi se ve al ejecutarlo]

He visto por hay algo de añadir una View al final pero no se como se haria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagino que `+id/frameResultados` es la variable a la que llamaste `contenedor` dentro del codigo java. Siendo asi yo armaria el xml de esta forma:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="#FF9999"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameResultados"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#9999FF"
        />
</ScrollView>
```

Por regla general los `ScrollView` van siempre en `match_parent` y el `LinearLayout` que llevan dentro en `wrap_content`. Se hace asi para que el linear logre agrandarse tanto como necesite y en caso de superar el tamaño del scroll, que al ser match_parent tiene un limite de tamaño, aparesca la barra para poder scrollear. Si el scroll fuese wrap_content, se ajustaria al tamaño de su contenido y nunca necesitaria scrollear, porque su contenido siempre cabe dentro, aunque finalmente se saldra de la pantalla y no sera visible.

Te recomiendo ademas que cuando tengas problemas con layouts que no se muestran, al menos no como vos esperas que lo hagan, les pongas color de background a todos, si es un color suave y medio transparente mejor. Te puede ahorrar horas de no saber que esta pasando.

Comment: Como siempre un crack,muchas gracias,funciona como un tiro